# DatePicker custom Numberpicker Style not working after change

Tags: android, custom-component

i have a custom date picker thats extends date picker.

I have initialized the month style when it loads the component:

```
private void updateCustomStyle() {
    ViewGroup childPicker = (ViewGroup)
                findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month" /*rest is:
                day, year*/, "id", "android"));

                EditText textview = (EditText)
                        childPicker.getChildAt(0);
                textview.setTextSize(35);
                textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                textview.invalidate();

}
```

After this the datepicker is loaded the month font size is bigger and the color is green. The problem happens after i scroll the month to another month, i have a date change listener that i've defined upon initialization:

```
this.init(agora.getYear(), agora.getMonth(), agora.getDate(),
            this.getOnDataChangedListener());
```

And on the data change listener i have this call:

```
@Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            updateCustomStyle();
        }
```

But still after i scroll to another month it goes back to the original style. Any suggestions on this?

This approach works on Android 3.1 and 4.0. The problems occurs on android 4.1.2 and greater. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After done a lot of research i've seen that you cant do that selection style on android 4.1.X like you could do on previous versions. What you can do is to create a class that extends NumberPicker and add this code:

```
if (child instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText) child).setTextSize(35);
}
```

but still you are not able to use a different style for selected numbers, so what i did is to use simonVT numberpicker (https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) wich after some customization solved the problem.